# Is there a way to make my own chalkboard paint without using unsanded grout?

Tags: paint, grout

I'm trying to create my own chalkboard paint (where I'm from, we don't seem to have any stores that sell chalkboard paint, nor unsanded grout in the entire city) and I see all the DIY posts out there saying you need "unsanded" grout. I'd like to avoid trial and error because the grout isn't as cheap as I thought it would be so my question is:

Is there a way to create chalkboard paint without using unsanded grout?

Answer (score 1):

You need unsanded grout, paint, and chalk.

Mix your unsanded grout.

Then add the unsanded grout to your paint.  The ratio is about 1 unsanded grout to 10 paint.

Then you have to mix really well.  If hand mixing this could be a good 10-20 minutes.

Paint section.

Let it dry a day.

Rub chalk all over the paint very thickly.  Let it sit for about a half hour.  Wipe of chalk with rag or eraser - nothing wet.

Should be good to use.

Comment: Any thoughts on the kind of paint?  Latex or Oil?  What about the paint finish: matte, gloss?

Comment: I used a oil based paint with a semi-gloss.  I think latex would work fine although I would wait a long long time (2-3 months) before touching it with moisture.  So that kind of limits the cleaning possibilities.

Comment: why the 2-3 month wait? Also, most chalkboard paint I've used is matte. I suppose any finish would work, but matte is likely the more traditional blackboard look.

Comment: Most chalkboard paint is matte but you will get a more matted look with grout added in.  I have made my own chalkboard paint and actually did a large wall in my kid's room a few years ago and it still works well.  It was oil based semi-gloss (cleans easier).  For latex you could probably use it after a couple days but again would not hit it with even a damp sponge - if you rub it with moisture before it cures you have a chance of taking strips with you.

Comment: He's asking for an unsanded grout solution.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say he's asking for a solution that doesn't use "unsanded grout".

Answer (score 0):

Back when I was a child, I remember making a chalkboard from a piece of plywood, finishing it with just ordinary black, matt-finish paint.

Whether that will work for you or not will depend on the finish of surface you are looking to cover.

Answer (score -2):

I've not tried this but I've heard you can mix baking soda into the acrylic paint with a ratio of around 1 tsp to 1/4 cup of paint.

See here: [Make your own chalkboard and paint](http://www.yourbetterstyle.com/2011/01/make-your-own-chalk-board-and-paint/)

Comment: Has anyone tried this? I can't afford to buy an entire can/gallon of acrylic paint - it is too expensive where i am (and i haven't bought because i still don't have unsanded grout)